# How to change mat-icon stroke width

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-icon

I use custom icon with the default mat-icon with angular. Yet, the mat icon are a bit too thick compared to the one I've created.

I know those icons are treated like fonts, but is it somehow possible to change it like we change the stroke from an svg?

#### Example

The `manage_accounts` icon will have the same thickness as the glob
*(I'm using the `class="material-icons-outlined"` to have the outlined version of the logo)*

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution

1. Go over the [google icons website](https://fonts.google.com/icons)
2. Make the adjustment the way you like it
3. Select any icon
4. In the right side, you'll have the "Static icon font" shown like this
   [image]
5. Copy the url
6. Past it in your browser
7. It will show you the `@font-face` to be using
8. Past those information, as follow, in your app

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons Outlined'; // Add Outlined if needed
  font-weight: 200; // The choosen font-weight
  font-style: normal;
  src:
    local('Material Icons Outlined'), // Add Outlined if needed
url('https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialsymbolsoutlined/v166/kJF1BvYX7BgnkSrUwT8OhrdQw4oELdPIeeII9v6oDMzByHX9rA6RzaxHMPdY43zj-jCxv3fzvRNU22ZXGJpEpjC_1v-p_4MrImHCIJIZrDAvHOejbd5zrDAt.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-display: fallback;
}
```

#### Use it locally for faster load

In case you're having an app and which to have it instant load *(I'm talking about hybrid app)*

1. Copy the url in your browser `https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialsymbolsoutlined/v166/kJF1BvYX7BgnkSrUwT8OhrdQw4oELdPIeeII9v6oDMzByHX9rA6RzaxHMPdY43zj-jCxv3fzvRNU22ZXGJpEpjC_1v-p_4MrImHCIJIZrDAvHOejbd5zrDAt.woff2`
2. This will download the file in your laptop
3. Move the font in your asset forlder
4. Change the target url ->

```
  src:
    local('Material Icons Outlined'), // Add Outlined if needed
    local('MaterialIconsOutlined-Light'), // My file name
    url('/assets/fonts/MaterialIconsOutlined-Light.woff2') format('woff2');
```

6. Should work just fine

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

After my research, I found out only these things.

All material icon is Google fonts, so you can change the size and stroke by using CSS properties `font-size` and `font-weight`, but there are some limitations.

If you are using **Angular Material** (mat-icon).

In that way, if you open `index.html` you will find there:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

that `font-family` provides only `font-weight: normal (400)`, so you can't change its weight to less than 400.

So the way to use, for ex: `font-weight: 200`, is refuse to use `<mat-icon></mat-icon>` and replace it with material icons https://fonts.google.com/icons.

All that you need is to replace in `index.html` link to fonts you want to use and provide a font-weight parameter `wght@200`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:wght@200" />
```

And then in your component change implementation to

```
<span class="material-symbols-outlined">invert_colors</span>
```

So in that way of implementation, you will have a thinner icon that you can resize with the `font-size` property.

Also, you can pass more parameters to the font link, more details here:
https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/material_symbols

And in case when you register a custom svg then inside `mat-icon` will be your svg, then you can try to add `stroke` and `stroke-width` properties.

```
<mat-icon style="stroke-width: 0.1; stroke: aqua" [svgIcon]="'custom-svg'"></mat-icon>
```

Comment: Damn, thx a lot for the detailed answer, +1 already for the research. 

I wont be testing what you wrote, since it's for me a requirement to use `mat-icon`, but since it does exists in the frame of the google font, it will surely exists in the `mat-icon` library in the future.

Thx a lot though, will mark this as accepted answer till we find a better solution :)

Comment: Tnx) Hope that really saves some time for someone.

Comment: In case you're interested, I've found a solution while keep using `mat-icon` :)

Answer (score 0):

`mat-icon` are fonts, I'm not sure in angular but you can try style them using the following properties:

```
.classname_of_the_icon{
     font-weight: 100 !important; // any weight you want your icon to be [bold, normal, 100, 200, ..., 800]
     font-size: 12px !important; // any size you want your icon to be
}
```

**The `!important;` allows us to override default `mat-icon` styles**, Let me know if it works Good Luck

Comment: It work for the `font-weight: 600` and does make the icon thicker! but sadly it isn't working to make then thinner...

Comment: try the `font-weight` that is less probably 100 and don't forget to use `!important`-good luck if you find this helpufull vote for the answer

Comment: I did the way you explained and it did not worked. I've tried every possible size. But was worth trying it.

Comment: @JulianoVargas No, sadly not. But be sure I'll post my answer if I do. Also, I had to create a new library with my own icons that I then import and use with mat-icon...
Also, think about upvoting the question if an answer to it would help you, it makes it more visible ;)

Comment: Thanks @RaphaëlBalet, I have no option but ditch the icon and use symbols instead which is customisable ref: https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.query=home&icon.set=Material+Symbols

Comment: @JulianoVargas Could be an Idea, but it doesn't seems to be ready yet from the angular perspective.